# hibernate More than one row with the given identifier

Tags: hibernate, junit

So I know this questions looks like a duplicate.  But it's not.  I have a unit test and I run it and I get this error:
More than one row with the given identifier exists.  So I put a break point where it happens and then when it freezes on the line I evaluate it and sure enough I get the error.  If I immediately evaluate it a second time...the error goes away and I get my singular result I am expecting.  It's almost like hibernate is out of sync with itself somehow.  Also I only get this error from the unit test.
Has anyone ever had a similar experience?  I've tried `.flush(), .clear()` and all sorts of other things.  When the test is not running there are no records at all in the database with the id that it tells me is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hallelujah!  I found the problem.  Apparently I had some `DAO.clear()` calls in the setup() method on the test itself.  I'm not sure what they were doing there.  Or how in the heck having them would cause hibernate to have the issue it was displaying.  However once I had removed the Hibernate `.clear()` calls from the test setup data the error went away all together.  I'm guessing not too many people/projects use the Hibernate `clear()` call and so perhaps I found some weird bug related to it.  **BEWARE the `clear()`**.....

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the Entity relation `@OneToOne`, one of the both entity will contain two records, so it will fail finding or loading by ID as the result will be double records.